# what does the following expression mean?

Tags: notation

I need to make a program to calculate the values of some variables, but i am stuck at this expression. I dont really understand the meaning of the last term (Xij).

I already tried searching on google, but i didn't find anything that could help me.

I just need to know how to evaluate that last term, Thanks.

[image: Expression]

Comment: Where did you get this equation from?

Answer (score 0):

A symbol with two indices often denotes the components of a matrix - you can think of it as a two dimensional array. From the equation it looks like $c_jx^j_i$ is a matrix multiplying a vector from the right.